# How do I re-include a class into the build path in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: build, path, intellij-idea

I accidentally excluded a class from the build path, from the compiler errors pane, and I can't figure out how to get it back.

The class isn't visible from any other classes, and it was right before I clicked that fateful menu option.

The class has a little "x" on the icon, whereas none of my other classes do.

**EDIT:**
Figured it out myself.
Go to Settings>Project Settings>Compiler>Excludes and delete the entry

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Project Settings -> Compiler -> Excludes and delete the entry

Comment: My version of Intellij has no settings menu

Comment: Settings is under the File Menu. You can also navigate using the CTRL-SHIFT-A and type in "setting"

Comment: This worked for me. Just needed to get to the location to remove the class for the excludes

Answer (score 16):

**2018 update**

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Excludes
```