# How to re-include excluded paths in Intellij when using Maven

Tags: intellij-idea

I am working on a multi level maven based project. One of the modules had dependencies issues and I had excluded it: now I wish to reenable/re-include that module.

The IJ documentation says to go to

```
File | Settings | Compiler | Excludes
```

However that option reports "No excludes".  Apparently the above documentation does apply to Maven built projects

Note the above is also the suggested way for another question with similar title [How do I re-include a class into the build path in Intellij IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132467/how-do-i-re-include-a-class-into-the-build-path-in-intellij-idea) . *So please do not mark this question as a "duplicate".*

I also tried :

```
File | Project Structure | Modules.
```

But there was no mention of excluded paths there either.

Comment: You can exclude single files from compilation, but it seems you excluded a whole module? I'm not sure if I understand your question: What exactly did you exclude? And how?

Comment: @morpheus05   I excluded entire directories - which correspond to maven sub-modules. I did this by right clicking from  Project Explorer and using "Mark | Mark as excluded"